# How do I make a shallow copy of a Perl hash reference?

Tags: perl, hash, shallow-copy

I want to push a reference to a hash. By that I mean I want to push a reference to a new hash that is a shallow copy of the hash I am given.

How do I create the shallow copy?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just copy it:

```
 my %copy = %$hash;
```

If you want another reference, just expand the original reference in the anonymous hash constructor:

```
 my $copy = { %$hash };
```

For those wondering about shallow copies: this sort of assignment only makes new values for the top level keys. Any values that are references will still be the same reference in the new hash. That is, you can replace a value in the new hash without changing the original hash. If you merely change the value, such as pushing a new item onto an anonymous array value, both hashes get the change because they share the same reference. As such, shallow copies are usually not what you want.

Comment: Interestingly enough, to create an anonymous copy of a referenced hash, the syntax is `%{{%$hash}}`. I had it as `%{%$hash}`, which worked (without the copying part - it returned the original referenced hash, rather than a copy) in Perl 5.8.8, but failed in 5.16...

Comment: notice that `$a = $hash;` is a copy by ref, i.e. the exact same reference, then `%b = %$hash;` is a shallow copy of the (dereferenced) hash, although `%b` is not a reference, then `$c  = { %$hash }` wold be a reference to the shallow copy expanded within an anonymous hash. While in the case you mention `%{{%$hash}}` from the inner most you first derefence then expand into anonymous hash and ultimately dereference that outer hash, i.e. it is not a reference at the end.